# how to translate data in hindi and other local language

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to translate english to other indian languages like punjabi, marathi and more.I have created an module. In which Getiing product collection. once I reacieved the data in english I can translate into into india laguages. Array I recieved in english I want to convert all the element of array in hindi and rest of content, Like CMS pages contnet, Order Content Etc.

**Product collection**

**Controller file of Extension**

```
public function chnageslang(){

             $Option = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_option_collection')->addFieldToSelect('product_id');
            $Option->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id');
            $entityIds = new Zend_Db_Expr($Option->getSelect()->__toString());


            if (!empty($n_collection['collection'])) {
                $prod[$h]['type'] = $this->__('New Arrival');
                $prod[$h]['type_id'] = 'new';                    
                $newcollection = $this->collectionDetail($n_collection['collection']);
                $prod[$h]['product'] = $newcollection ? $newcollection : array();
                ++$h;
            } else {
                $prod[$h]['type'] = $this->__('New Product');
                $prod[$h]['type_id'] = 'new';
                $prod[$h]['product'] = array();
                ++$h;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a locale file in your language and translate every string in csv with "english string, your language string"

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your word in traduction function, then you create your local translate

1. `<?php echo $this->__('Your word'); ?>`

   or

   `<?php echo Mage::helper('yourhelper')->__('Your word'); ?>`
2. you create your local file in : **app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/locale/{language_ISO}/translate.csv**

   ```
   "Your word","translation"
   ```
3. choose your store view of this language, then you'll find your translation so pretty